# Proving that if |x| < 1, then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-writing, induction

I'm supposed to use the answer from the previous question:

> Prove inductively that for any real number $x \neq 1$, for any integer $n \geq 0$, we have $$1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}−1}{x−1}$$

I got the answer to this, it's a rather easy simplification of the geometric sum by assuming the hypothesis is correct.

However, I'm not sure exactly how to prove the following using THAT result:

Prove using the answer above, that if |x| < 1, then  $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}=\frac{1}{1-x}$

I'm completely lost.

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{i=0}^{n=\infty}x^i =\frac{1}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: Don't refer to "the previous question".

Comment: Be aware that the notation $\sum^{n=\infty}$ is not used.

Comment: @sav Yes, exactly, my apologies. Fixed.

Comment: Are you supposed to give a full-fledged epsilon-delta proof, or are you allowed to use the fact that $|x|^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ if $|x|\lt1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra I think I'm allowed to use that. We haven't done any epsilon-delta proofs. I can't tie the answer I got previously to the answer $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Also, if you ask me, I feel that it's silly to prove things I've done in Calculus II that I KNOW are true.

Comment: @FilipKłosiewicz, isn't it enough to note that $${x^{n+1}-1\over x-1}={1-x^{n+1}\over1-x}={1\over1-x}-{x^{n+1}\over1-x}\to{1\over1-x}-{0\over1-x}={1\over1-x}$$ if $|x|\lt1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra I think you just blew my mind with that, since n heads to infinity. Holy smokes that makes it so clear to me, and I've been starting at it for over an hour.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k:=\lim_{n\to\infty }\sum_{k=0}^nx^k.$$

Comment: I would add that RHS is the known mathematical objects that defines the symbol in LHS.

Comment: @Joe: thank you.

Comment: @Surb I see your hint, but I'm lost because doesn't the first series diverge, and this one converges?

Comment: @FilipKłosiewicz: As you proved previously (or as you know), $$\sum_{k=0}^nx^k:=1+x+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

Comment: @FilipKłosiewicz, what exactly are you referring to when you say "the first series" and "this one"?

Comment: @BarryCipra First is the one I wrote for the problem initially, and this one is the one I'm trying to prove.

Comment: To prove $$1+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x},$$ either use induction, or compute directly $(1-x)(1+...+x^n)$. @FilipKłosiewicz

Answer (score 0):

Some big hints

Define:

$S_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=n} x^i$

Prove that

$x S_n(x)  + 1 = S_{n+1}(x)$  **Equation (1)**

Next prove

$S_{n+1}(x) - S_n(x) = x^{n+1}$ **Equation (2)**

Finally substitue our definition of $S_{n+1}(x)$  from equation 1 into equation 2

Factorize so that $S_n(x)$ only appears once. Then rearrange the expression so it's of the form  $S_n(x) = ...$